# Input radio button next to text

Tags: html, css

I've tried to put text after the input radio button, but the text is always under the radio button. I have used the CSS that is shown, but I get the same results.

**CSS:**

```
<style>  

.sp-list .sp-item {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sp-item {
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  margin:1em 0;
}

.sp-input-radio {
  float:left;
  margin:0.5em 1em 0 0;
}

.sp-label {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
<ul class="sp-list">
<li class="sp-item">
<input name="answer" value="1" id="poll-1-1" class="sp-input-radio" type="radio">
<label for="poll-1-1" class="sp-label"> Ok very nice </label>
</li>
</fieldset>
```

I tried this but can't get the text to show after the input radio in the same line.

Comment: Is there enough space to hold them in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove the `float:left;` on the input and it'll line up like you wanted - **[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ET2zJ/)**.

Just change:

```
.sp-input-radio {
  float:left;
  margin:0.5em 1em 0 0;
}
```

to:

```
.sp-input-radio {
  margin:0.5em 1em 0 0;
}
```

You could also take out the margin in that class if necessary (unless that's how you wanted it spaced originally).

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for your solution and found out that your radio button had the following css property

```
margin:0.5em 1em 0 0;
```

which mite be causing problems and i removed that:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/u7n4h/ hope it helps